# Is it possible/when will it be possible to connect to Azure B2C as a Daemon / Non interactive user?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trialling Azure B2C Customer Preview and have configured a new application, set up policies e.t.c and I now want to write some integration tests that use a non-interactive flow to connect and interact with my protected WebApi services.

However, I have just read the following quote:

> Daemons/Server Side Apps
>
> Apps that contain long running processes or that operate without the
>   presence of a user also need a way to access secured resources, such
>   as Web APIs. These apps can authenticate and get tokens using the
>   app's identity (rather than a user's delegated identity) using the
>   OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow.
>
> This flow is not currently supported by Azure AD B2C - which is to say
>   that apps can only get tokens after an interactive user flow has
>   occurred. The client credentials flow will be added in the near
>   future.

from [this link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps.md) which suggests that what I am trying to do is not yet possible. Can anyone from the Azure team tell me whether this information is up to date, and better yet a rough timescale for delivery on this feature?